# Zip -recursive direcotry and it start file

Tags: bash, shell-script, directory, zip

I am trying to zip a folder that contains others files and folder by getting as parameter the directory and the zip name. My script is in antoher folder than the one that I should zip (just a ..). I try using this code :

```
zip -j $2 $1/* $1
```

But the main folder and the other folder aren't there.

Comment: Instead of $2 $1/* $1, please show the real names that you want zip to operate on.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us what operating system you are using; ii) show us an example directory structure (you can use the command `tree` to get this) so we understand what you are trying to do. iii) show us your expected output and iv) explain what you get instead of the expected output.

Comment: Double-quote the parameters - i.e. `zip -j "$2" "$1"/* "$1"`.   You haven't given enough info to tell if this will solve your problem, but you should do it anyway. Unquoted variable/parameter expansion is a bug waiting to happen.